# SQL query- number of statuses in percentage

Tags: sql, db2

I have table SR with some records with statuses (more then 5 records this is just example ):

```
ID   STATUS
1    NEW
2    OPEN
3    OPEN
4    PENDING
5    PENDING
```

I want to get table  in this format:

```
STATUS   PERCENTAGE

NEW       20
OPEN      40
PENDING   40
```

I wrote SQL query but I can't make it work:

```
with HELPTABLE as
(select count(*) as NUMBER
from SR
)
select 
    SR.STATUS,
    (count (*)) / (HELPTABLE.NUMBER) * 100
from 
    SR, HELPTABLE
group by 
    SR.status
```

Using HELPTABLE I am getting as result 5.

If I don't put `HELPTABLE.NUMBER` I am getting some result.

If I divide (`count (*)`) with let's say with 2 I am getting result, but if I put `HELPTABLE.NUMBER` which is 5 I am getting an error.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing SQL Server 2005 or higher

```
select
     T.STATUS, 100.0 * COUNT(*) / Total
from
    (
     SELECT 
        ID, STATUS, COUNT(*) OVER () AS Total
     FROM
        SR
    ) T
group by 
     T.status, T.Total
```

Comment: I am using DB2. I am having some  strange result. I have to keep my WITH statement above your query?

Comment: Thanks for your help, it works. I am just wondering  why I wasn't able to do it with WITH statement? It seems correct to me? Sorry for bothering, if you know maybe the answer (correct query with WITH) if not nevermind

Comment: @user1191860: I'm not sure, sorry